# certain inequality for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:D=B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ be holomorphic embedding(one-one but it may or may not be onto) with $f(0)=0$. Let $s>0$ be such that $B(0,s)\subseteq f(D)$. Then how to prove the following:$$\liminf_{r\uparrow 1} |f(re^{i\theta_0})|\geq s,$$ where $\theta_0$ is arbitrarily fixed.\
Few remarks:-

1. $\liminf$ is calculated over line segment from origin to the point $e^{i\theta_0}$ on the unit circle. For any $\theta_0$,  portion of this line from origin till the point $se^{i\theta_0}$ lies within the image set(from given condition).\
2. $\liminf_{r\uparrow 1}|f(re^{i\theta_0})|=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} \left(\inf_{0<|r-1|<\delta}|f(re^{i\theta_0})|\right)\geq \inf_{1-\delta<r<1}|f(re^{i\theta_0})|$ for every $\delta$. How to go ahead after this.

Comment: f is assumed injective yes?

Comment: @Conrad yes  $f$ is injective but may or may not be onto.

Comment: You're taking the $\liminf$ of a complex valued function?

Comment: @zhw edited, it is supposed to be modulus of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ideas:

1. The hypotheses imply $f:D\to f(D)$ is a homeomorphism.
2. Thus if $d(z_n,\partial D)\to 0,$ then $d(f(z_n),\partial f(D))\to 0.$
3. Since $D(0,s)\subset f(D),$ no point of $D(0,s)$ is in $\partial f(D).$ It follows that for a sequence $z_n$ as in 2, we get $\liminf |f(z_n)| \ge s.$

As an aside, I didn't see what a radial approach had do with it, and I didn't use $f(0)=0.$